# Javascript calculation returns NaN, when only first 2 sum inserted

Tags: javascript, html

```
function kanded_arvutus() 
  {
  var deebet1 = document.getElementById("deebet1").value;
  var kreedit1 = document.getElementById("kreedit1").value;
  var deebet2 = document.getElementById("deebet2").value;
  var kreedit2 = document.getElementById("kreedit2").value;


  var kokku_deebet = parseFloat(deebet1)+parseFloat(deebet2);
  document.getElementById("kokku_deebet").value = kokku_deebet.toFixed(2);   
  var kokku_kreedit = parseFloat(kreedit1)+parseFloat(kreedit2);
  document.getElementById("kokku_kreedit").value = kokku_kreedit.toFixed(2);     
  }
```

and this is html

```
<input onClick="kanded_arvutus();" onChange="kanded_arvutus();" type="text" class="form-control" name="deebet'.$i.'" id="deebet'.$i.'"  placeholder="0" value="">             

<input value="" onClick="kanded_arvutus();" onChange="kanded_arvutus();" type="text" class="form-control" name="kreedit'.$i.'" id="kreedit'.$i.'"  placeholder="0">


<input type="text" class="form-control field" name="kokku_deebet" value="" id="kokku_deebet" placeholder="0">

<input type="text" class="form-control field" name="kokku_kreedit" value="" placeholder="0" id="kokku_kreedit">
```

and if i insert only kreedit1 and deebet1 values, then jquery returns NAN , but if i insert deebet2 and kreedit2 also, then working.

someone maybe see, what wrong here ?

Thanks in advance, aimar.

Comment: can you show us the rendered html.

Comment: That's because `parseFloat("")` returns `NaN`, and `NaN + anything` still is `NaN`.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with jQuery. It's plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the variables are not null or notdefined as below, before the addition,

```
if (typeof(deebet1) != 'undefined' && deebet1 != null && typeof(deebet2) != 'undefined' && deebet2 != null)
{
    var kokku_deebet = parseFloat(deebet1)+parseFloat(deebet2);
    document.getElementById("kokku_deebet").value = kokku_deebet.toFixed(2);
}

if (typeof(kreedit1) != 'undefined' && kreedit1 != null && typeof(kreedit2) != 'undefined' && deebet2 != null)
{
    var kokku_deebet = parseFloat(kreedit1)+parseFloat(kreedit2);
    document.getElementById("kokku_kreedit").value = kokku_deebet.toFixed(2);
}
```

As John suggested you can just use the following, which will check whether the variables has any real values.

```
if (deebet1 && deebet2)
    {
        var kokku_deebet = parseFloat(deebet1)+parseFloat(deebet2);
        document.getElementById("kokku_deebet").value = kokku_deebet.toFixed(2);
    }

    if (kreedit1 && kreedit2)
    {
        var kokku_deebet = parseFloat(kreedit1)+parseFloat(kreedit2);
        document.getElementById("kokku_kreedit").value = kokku_deebet.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Comment: is this ok, when i but 0 in input value ?
or better do it your way ?

Comment: I think it is your call, but it always good to check if it has a value before the addition. Provided you will use reg exp or some kind of validation to accept only decimal or numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a empty string from the input values and trying to parse it as a number. That's why it is Nan. You need to check if it is not empty (and if it's empty set a default value, maybe 0).

```
if(deebet1 != "") {

}
```

and so forth..